# Non-spacing characters in curses

Tags: c, locale, ncurses, curses

I was trying to write a basic program to print ā (a with overline) in C using **curses** and **non-spacing characters**. I have set the locale to en_US.UTF-8 and I am able to print international language characters using that. This code only prints a without overline. I am getting similar results with ncurses too. What else do I need to do to get ā on screen?

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {  
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    int s = 0x41;     // represents 'a'
    int ns = 0x0305; // represents COMBINING OVERLINE (a non-spacing character)

    assert(wcwidth(ns) == 0);

    wchar_t wstr[] = { s, ns, L'\0'};
    cchar_t *cc;
    int x = setcchar(cc, wstr, 0x00, 0, NULL);
    assert(x == 0);

    add_wch(cc);

    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Two calls to `add_wch`, one with each character.

Comment: You're also passing an uninitialized pointer to `setcchar`.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE - I thought I deleted that comment before I even posted it.  Thanks.

Comment: The pointer passed as the first arg to `setcchar` needs to point to an array of sufficient size to hold one `cchar_t` for each `wchar_t` in the input string.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Yeah, it should be done that way. I have tried by allocating sufficiently large array too and making 2 calls, first for spacing character and then for non-spacing at same screen location. But still not working.

Comment: Can you show your updated code as an addition to the end of the question without deleting context of the original question? A "here's what I tried and it's still not working" section at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The curses calls need a pointer to **data**, not just a pointer.

It's okay to pass a null-terminated array for the wide-characters, but the pointer for the `cchar_t` data needs some repair.

Here's a fix for the program:

```
> diff -u foo.c.orig foo.c
--- foo.c.orig  2020-05-21 19:50:48.000000000 -0400
+++ foo.c       2020-05-21 19:51:46.799849136 -0400
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@
 #include <wchar.h>
 #include <assert.h>

-int main() {  
+int main(void) {  
     setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
     initscr();
     int s = 0x41;     // represents 'a'
@@ -12,11 +12,11 @@
     assert(wcwidth(ns) == 0);

     wchar_t wstr[] = { s, ns, L'\0'};
-    cchar_t *cc;
-    int x = setcchar(cc, wstr, 0x00, 0, NULL);
+    cchar_t cc;
+    int x = setcchar(&cc, wstr, 0x00, 0, NULL);
     assert(x == 0);

-    add_wch(cc);
+    add_wch(&cc);

     refresh();
     getch();
```

That produces (on xterm) a "A" with an overbar:

[image]

(For what it's worth, **`0x61`** is "a", while **`0x41`** is "A").

Comment: yeah this work if I launch xterm from Ubuntu 18.0. But the same doesn't work with xterm of BSD system. I have set the locale as mentioned in question, as well as XTERM_LOCALE env variable using ```xterm -en en_US.UTF-8 ``` command.

Comment: Is there any way to just dump that screen and see if the character is placed correctly and just rendering is not correct?

Comment: Using the FreeBSD port for xterm , you'd have to run on the UTF-8 encoding, e.g., via a resource setting, a menu setting (control-right-mouse).  You can see what's set in the control-right-mouse menu.  In a quick check, that works with FreeBSD 12.  In Debian (Ubuntu provides no improvements), a resource-setting makes it start in UTF-8 encoding because the system locale uses UTF-8 encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically correct aside from the declaration of `cc`. You'd be well-advised to hide the cursor, though; I think it is preventing you from seeing the overbar incorrectly rendered in the following character position.

I modified your code as follows:

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main() {  
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    initscr();
    int s = 0x41;     // represents 'A'
    int ns = 0x0305;  // represents COMBINING OVERLINE (a non-spacing character)

    assert(wcwidth(ns) == 0);

    wchar_t wstr[] = { s, ns, L'\0'};
    cchar_t cc;                                 /* Changed *cc to cc */
    int x = setcchar(&cc, wstr, 0x00, 0, NULL); /* Changed cc to &cc */
    assert(x == 0);
    set_curs(0);                                /* Added to hide the cursor */
    add_wch(&cc);                               /* Changed cc to &cc */

    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

I tested on a kubuntu system, since that's what I have handy. The resulting program worked perfectly on xterm (which has ugly fonts) but not on konsole. On konsole, it rendered the overbar in the following character position, which is clearly a rendering bug since the overbar appears on top of the following character if there is one. After changing konsole's font to Liberation Mono, the test program worked perfectly.

The rendering bug is not going to be easy to track down because it is hard to reproduce, although from my experiments it seems to show up reliably when the font is DejaVu Sans Mono. Curiously, my system is set up to use non-spacing characters from DejaVu Sans Mono as substitutes in other fonts, such as Ubuntu Mono, and when these characters are used as substitutes, the spacing appears to be correct. However, Unicode rendering is sufficiently intricate that I cannot actually prove that the substitute characters really come from the configured font, and the rendering bug seems to come and go. It may depend on the font cache, although I can't prove that either.

If I had more to go on I'd file a bug report, and if I get motivated to look at this some more tomorrow, I might find something. Meanwhile, any information that other people can provide will undoubtedly be useful; at a minimum, that should include operating system and console emulator, with precise version numbers, and a list of fonts tried along with an indication whether they succeeded or not.

It's not necessary to use ncurses to see this bug, by the way. It's sufficient to test in your shell:

```
printf '\u0041\u0305\u000a'
```

will suffice. I found it interesting to test

```
printf '\u0041\u0305\u0321\u000a'
```

as well.

The system I tested it on:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
$ konsole --version
konsole 17.12.3
$ # Fonts showing bug
$ otfinfo -v /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf 
Version 2.37
$ # Fonts not showing bug
$ otfinfo -v /usr/share/fonts/truetype/liberation/LiberationMono-Regular.ttf 
Version 1.07.4
```

Comment: I am using the same system that you have specified with the corresponding versions matching. But in my case, this is not working. Instead, if I use 0x0303 (Tilde), that non-spacing character works perfectly fine. Can there be some issue with locale?

Comment: Is there any way to just dump that screen and see if the character is placed correctly and just rendering is not correct?

Comment: @algod: are you saying that changing the font in Konsole did not fix the problem? Also, I'm not sure what you mean by correct placement and incorrect rendering. Correct placement is part of correct rendering. In any event, the glyph renders as an overline, but in the wrong place.

Comment: Yes, changing the font didn't solve the problem. @rici I mean if I use some other terminal emulator and am not able to see non-spacing character for some reason, is there any way to just dump the screen content and check if it was placed there, but not visible for some reason.

Comment: @algod: Interesting. I wonder why it works on my system and not on yours. Anyway, there is no way of dumping the screen content in a useful form (unless you consider individual pixels to be useful.)

Answer (score -2):

There are multiple issues here. First, you're storing the result of `setcchar` to random memory at an uninitialized pointer, `cc`. Whenever a function takes a pointer for output, you need to pass the **address of an object** where the result will be stored, not an uninitialized pointer variable. The output must be an array of sufficient length to store the number of characters in the input. I'm not sure what the null termination convention is so to be safe I'd use:

```
cchar_t cc[3];
int x = setcchar(cc, wstr, 0x00, 0, NULL);
```

Then, the [`add_wch`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcurses/add_wch.html) function takes only a single character to add, and replaces or appends based on whether it's a spacing or non-spacing character. So you need to call it once for each character.

Comment: This is not correct: "the add_wch function takes only a single character to add". It can take up to `CCHARW_MAX` codepoints (5, at least in the installation of ncurses on my machine). All but the first must be non-spacing codepoints; the first one might or might not be. The complex character is spacing or not depending on whether the first codepoint is a spacing or not, and that is what influences `add_wch`. Note the phrase "the non-spacing **characters** of wch" (emph added) in your documentation link.